"Close as duplicate" boilerplate text changed
When the first vote to close-as-duplicate is cast, the Math SE software also posts a comment that says

This question is similar to: …. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Until recently the text was different:

Does this answer your question? …

and I think that before that it was something else.
When did the wording change?

This on metaSE is related.

Thanks.  I tried to post an answer so that I could mark the question as having been answered, but the software converted my answer into a comment.

This question is similar to: Is a new comment format for duplicate votes being tested?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Note that the comment is posted under your account so you are free to edit it as need be (I usually do so).

Here's an early and highly-upvoted meta post complaining about the "Does this answer your question" text: "Does this answer your question?" duplicate comment text is silly and confusing.  Here's a status post announcing that it was changed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401060/we-spent-a-sprint-addressing-your-requests-here-s-how-it-went.

@BillDubuque As in the meta SE thread, the comment then is not automatically deleted when the question is closed as a duplicate.

@Tyma Which may be the intended behavior - since the dupe closing comment may contain useful info (e.g. how the dupe applies , e.g. if it is a specialization of a general result).
